# Compiling gsl/atlas/cython

Tags: gcc, compilation, cython, gsl, atlas

I am new to the cython and gsl, and I am trying to learn.

I have written a small code snippet, which uses cython to write a module to compute least squares estimator, which is done in C using GSL.

I have a big trouble compiling the code. After trying for all day yesterday, here is what gets the code to work (the cython generated file is lsq.c and the native C is c_lsq.c)

```
gcc -fPIC -g  -o lsq.so -shared -O2 -I/home/user/anaconda/include/python2.7 -I/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/atlas/libinclude -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/atlas/lib -lcblas -latlas  -Wl,--whole-archive /usr/local/lib/libgsl.a /usr/local/atlas/lib/libcblas.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lm lsq.c c_lsq.c /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so
```

This is awfully long and it is very weird that this seems to be the only way I can make it to work. However,

1. Isn't -lcblas and -latlas redundant?
2. Why do I have to ship the /usr/local/atlas/lib/libsatlas.so?
3. Is there are way to compile the whole program by two steps (i.e. first steps to compile c_lsq.c and second lsq.c)

Thank you very much for any advice.

(ps. The compiler is gcc-4.9 on ubuntu 14.04)